# Subtract a vector to each row of a dataframe

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe

My dataframe looks like this :

```
fruits = pd.DataFrame({'orange': [10, 20], 'apple': [30, 40], 'banana': [50, 60]})


   apple  banana  orange
0     30      50      10
1     40      60      20
```

And I have this vector (its also a dataframe)

```
sold = pd.DataFrame({'orange': [1], 'apple': [2], 'banana': [3]})

   apple  banana  orange
0      2       3       1
```

I want to subtract this vector to each row of the initial dataframe to obtain a dataframe which looks like this

```
   apple  banana  orange
0   28.0    47.0     9.0
1   38.0    57.0     19.0
```

I tried :

```
print fruits.subtract(sold, axis = 0)
```

And the output is

```
   apple  banana  orange
0   28.0    47.0     9.0
1    NaN     NaN     NaN
```

It worked only for the first line. I could create a dataframe filled with the vector for each row. Is there a more efficient way to subtract this vector ? I don't want to use a loop.

Comment: Small note: I assume you use the sub method (with axis parameter) to correctly align the dfs but as they explained in the answers, you need a series for that. Once you have a series, you can also use `fruits - sold.squeeze()` or `fruits - sold.iloc[0, :]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
fruits.sub(sold.iloc[0, :])
```

[image]

What you tried before didn't work because `sold` is a dataframe and the subtraction will try to align both `columns` and `index`.  `sold.iloc[0, :]` gets at the first row and is a series thus will work as you intended.

Answer (score 4):

convert the df to a series using `squeeze` and pass `axis=1`:

```
In [6]:
fruits.sub(sold.squeeze(), axis=1)

Out[6]:
   apple  banana  orange
0     28      47       9
1     38      57      19
```

The conversion is necessary as by design arithmetic operations between dfs will align on indices and columns, by passing a Series this allows you to subtract from each row in the df the row from the other df.