# Subtract vector to each row dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to subtract a vector from each row of my data frames. I am using Python 3 with Anaconda running on Windows.

Here are the data frames that I have:

**dataframe 1 (1 row, 5 cols):**

```
    Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
45  94.0    94  92.0    90    86
```

**dataframe 2 (17981 rows, 5 cols):**

```
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
0  85.0    98  78.0    74    20
1  74.1    87  34.0    85    15 
..  ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
```

At first I tried just subtracting one vector to the other but I found myself with multiple NANs after which I tried and followed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38796548/subtract-a-vector-to-each-row-of-a-dataframe) and I did

```
df1 = df1.iloc[0,:]
df2.sub(df1)
```

but I still get an error that says:

```
ValueError: can only convert an array of size 1 to a Python scalar
```

Can anyone please help me and pointing out what I need to do?

Additional note, the shapes of both dataframes are:

```
df1 = (5,)
df2 = (17981,5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [134]: d2.sub(d1.iloc[0], axis=1)
Out[134]:
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
0  -9.0   4.0 -14.0 -16.0 -66.0
1 -19.9  -7.0 -58.0  -5.0 -71.0
```

or:

```
In [135]: d2 - d1.iloc[0].values
Out[135]:
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
0  -9.0   4.0 -14.0 -16.0 -66.0
1 -19.9  -7.0 -58.0  -5.0 -71.0
```

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you need ?

```
df2.sub(df1.values.tolist()[0],axis = 1)
Out[484]: 
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
0  -9.0   4.0 -14.0 -16.0 -66.0
1 -19.9  -7.0 -58.0  -5.0 -71.0
```